# How to properly use pandas vectorization?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, vectorization, apply

According to [an article](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6), the `vectorization` is much faster than `apply` a function to a pandas dafaframe column.

But I had a somehow special case like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'IP': [ '1.0.64.2', '100.23.154.63', '54.62.1.3']})

def compare3rd(ip):
    """Check if the 3dr part of an IP is greater than 100 or not"""
    ip_3rd = ip.split('.')[2]
    if int(ip_3rd) > 100:
        return True
    else:
        return False


# This works but very slow
df['check_results'] = df.IP.apply(lambda x: compare3rd(x))
print df

# This is supposed to be much faster
# But it doesn't work ...
df['check_results_2'] = compare3rd(df['IP'].values)
print df
```

Full error traceback look like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    df['check_results_2'] = compare3rd(df['IP'].values)
  File "test.py", line 6, in compare3rd
    ip_3rd = ip.split('.')[2]
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'split'
```

My question is: how do I properly use this `vectorization` method in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `str` in `pandas`

```
df.IP.str.split('.').str[2].astype(int)>100
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: IP, dtype: bool
```

Since you mention `vectorize`

```
import numpy as np
np.vectorize(compare3rd)(df.IP.values)
array([False,  True, False])
```

Comment: Thank you @Wen-Ben, this is a solution to the code in my question. However, my real problem is more complicated so I kinda have to use the `compare3rd(df.IP)` style. And how to do that is what I ultimately want to know. Maybe it is not doable I guess. A simple confirmation on that is helpful as well.

Comment: That's exactly what I need! Thank you!

Comment: It turned out that, for this special case, the `np.vectorize(myfunc)(Series)` method has the same speed as `pd.Series.apply` method.